# DirectShow is reseting my PC

Tags: directshow, reset, nvidia

I developed small application using DirectShow and code on next link:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/directxcapture.aspx

If i have 2nd display active, when I close application, it reset my PC.

How does it looks line? First, when I close application, for 0.5 is all ok, after that PC freezes for 1 sec, blue screen for 0.5 sec, and then reset.

I have Nvidia 7600GS video card in PC.

Is there maybe a problem with capture.Close(); method? Or it's video card?

Please help!

Comment: Any crash or visible error on the screen?  I'm leaning on drivers not handling a bug in your code well, if not (because that sounds like a triple fault).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're getting a [BSoD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bsod). Configure your computer to save a memory dump file or connect a kernel debugger, and you'll be able to get the bugcheck code and stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Update your drivers for your graphics card, this may solve your issue, but I'd suggest replacing that gfx card.

We've also seen this on the nVidia Quadro NVS cards and other business class quad head cards.

Most nVidia cards don't have this problem though, and it's not specific to nVidia.

Could also be poorly written webcam drivers.  Test this by using a different capture source for your program.  If it still crashes, it's likely to be your video card drivers.